# Delegate with a main method

Tags: c#, delegates, program-entry-point

I can't access my delegate in the main method. I think it has something to do with the static main. But I can't make my delegate static.

```
public delegate double Calculation(double number1, double number2);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
}
```

Comment: the modifier static is not valid for this item

Comment: You have to make the [_instance_ of the delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664604(v=vs.71).aspx) `static`.

Comment: The `delegate Calculation` is a Type. It is accessible just fine in Main(). The most relevant code is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate type you declared can certainly be used from `Main`:

```
public delegate double Calculation(double number1, double number2);

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Calculation x = null;
}
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/OOXL56068

Most likely you are confused about using delegates in general, and the static method `Main` has nothing to do with your problem whatsoever.